# Is a circle a multivalued function?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, definition, real-numbers, multivalued-functions

I don't really understand multi-valued function. I hope one of you can make me understand it. What I've learned from google, I suppose that a multi-valued function is a binary relation that maps the domain more than once to a single point (i can't describe it well).

So, here, can I conveniently claim that a circle (on the real plane) is a multi-valued function since from one point on the domain we can get $2$ points as the range?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A circle is a shape, not a function. You can describe a circle in the plane centered at the origin via $x^2+y^2=r^2$. However, if you were to express this as $y=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ you see that for every value of $x$, there are two values of $y$. So $y$ is multi-valued, therefore not a function.

Comment: The circle itself is not a function. It is described as the image of the map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2: t \to (r\sin(t), r\cos(t))$ which is single-valued. If you consider it to be the solution to $y^2 + x^2 = r^2$ then this is a multi-valued function of $x$. The more pedagogical example is the inverse of the function $x^2$.

Comment: @epiliam , please, make clear, why you made that opinion that the circle may not be a function.

Comment: @epiliam , why multivalue may not be a function? This also doesn’t seem a correct statement.

Comment: @Sergei A shape is a geometric object. A function is a mapping $f:X\to Y$. It consists of a rule, and two sets. By its very definition, a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) cannot be multi-valued. Note also that the [square-root function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) is a well defined, single-valued function, so your answer is wrong.

Comment: @epiliam, by the link that you provided: “For example, 4 and −4 are square roots of 16”. Could you, please, reconsider? Are we on the same page that square root and principal square root are different means?

Comment: @Sergei, keep reading the wiki page. You are wrong. I promise you that, but I will not be replying further. Perhaps someone else could explain in more detail.

Comment: @epiliam, “unique nonnegative square root, called the principal square root, which is denoted by √x”. Are we on the same page that square root and principal square root are different means?

Comment: Yes, it is correct that any function which graphical representation has multiple y for single x would be multi-value by disjunction at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle $S$ can be viewed as a binary relation on $\Bbb{R}$, simply because it is a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$. And indeed if $(x,y)\in S$ then also $(x,-y)\in S$, so if $y\neq0$ then this shows that $S$ is multivalued. **But** $S$ is not a function on $\Bbb{R}$, because it is not defined on all of $\Bbb{R}$; there is no $y\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $(2,y)\in S$, for example. So the circle cannot be viewed as a multivalued function on $\Bbb{R}$.

There are two ways to adjust your example to valid example of a multivalued function:

1. We can adjust the domain; viewing the circle $S$ as a subset of $[-1,1]\times\Bbb{R}$, or even $[-1,1]^2$, we do get a multivalued function. This of course relates to the fact that every positive real number has precisely $2$ square roots, i.e. the function
   $$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2},$$
   can also be interpreted as a $2$-valued function on the interval $[-1,1]$.
2. We can consider a *hyperbola* instead, for example the set of all $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ satisfying
   $$x^2-y^2=-1.$$
   I leave it to you to verify that this defines a $2$-valued function on all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Can i have a question please? I'm not sure or maybe don't understand about your first statement. I mean, if $(x,y)\in S \Rightarrow (x,-y)\in S$ I mean, for example i have a unit circle at $(1,2)$ as a center that means $(1,3)\in S$. But we know $(1,-3) \notin S$

Comment: By *"the circle"* I meant *"the unit circle"* throughout my answer, which is the circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin. For your circle you get $(x,4-y)\in S$ if $(x,y)\in S$, and I'm sure you can generalize this to any circle.

Answer (score -1):

$y=(R^2-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ is multivalue function because exponentiation to a negative even is multivalue by disjunction.

Yes, it is correct that any function which graphical representation has multiple y for single x would be multi-value by disjunction at that point.